# Representation theory of SO(p,q)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

For a long time now, I have tried to look for the representation theory of $SO(p,q)$. I am in particular interested in the unitary irreducible representations and the bilinear Hermitian form on the space of (homogeneous) functions. I know that for certain degrees, the representations are unitary, but I want to know the associated bilinear form. Any reference (other then Vilenkin for $SL(2,\mathbf{R})$) would be welcome :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/Knapp-Trapa.pdf and see if this is what you are looking for. In this set of notes Knapp and Trapa treat general semisimple Lie groups so you would have to specialize to the case of SO(p,q).

Comment: Not a specialist but afaik the full unitary dual in general is not known. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84624/unitary-irreps-of-op-q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite dimensional unitary representations of $SO(p,q)$ are discussed in section 9.2.9, 9.2.10 of the book

N.Vilenkin and A.Klimyk "Representations of Lie groups and special functions", Volume 2, Kluwer, 1993.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful!