# Book on $SL(2,C)$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation

Is there a book, which treats $SL(2,C)$ in detail as a group, Lie group, its Lie algebra, geometry of its subgroups etc.? It is often seen as an example in Lie Algebra/Group books but it always remains quite superficial and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Also book recommandations from (theoretical) physics are welcome.

Comment: There is a book by Serge Lang about, and literally called, $SL_2(R)$.

Comment: Yes, but $R\neq C$ or is there nothing additional to the $C$ case?

Comment: Brian Hall's book is pretty good.

Comment: There's a book 'Physics from Symmetry' by Jakob Schwichtenberg that describes its main features in the first few chapters.

Comment: It's isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spin}(1,3)$, so if you want to study it from the direction of Clifford algebras, that's another appoach.  Maybe even a more complete picture.  The Dirac gamma matrices generate $\operatorname{Cl}^{1,3}(\Bbb{R})$ in a representation on $\Bbb{C}^4$ and there it's found inside as the spin group of this Clifford algebra.

Comment: Mazorchuk has written a book on its Lie algebra, Lectures on sl_2(C)

Comment: If you want the list of connected subgroups of $SL(2,C)$, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646183/list-of-connected-lie-subgroups-of-mathrmsl2-mathbbc/650285#650285). The theory of finitely generated discrete subgroups of $SL(2,C)$ is quite complicated but is relatively well-understood. The classification of finite-dimensional complex representations of $SL(2,C)$ is covered in many places, pretty much in any textbook on representation theory of Lie groups. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234729/representation-theory-of-sop-q/3235026#3235026